# How to get data from PDF from URL having authentication using selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium2, pdf-file

I need to automate this flow where a PDF will be opened when i use the URL and enter the authentication.
This flow has to be automated using Selenium. I tried PDFbox API but it works only for URL without authentication

Comment: https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-extract-pdf-text-and-verify-using-selenium-webdriver-java did you try this what error are you getting.

Comment: Can you explain your requirement step-wise?

Comment: If you are looking for the PDF info, why boot up a full browser? What not to simply make an HTTP call for the PDF?